# Breaking a rod into small pieces; recursion step returns nothing useful

Tags: python, recursion, random

I have been learning python by myself and recursion is troublesome. We are given a starting piece of weight 2.0.  When the piece weight is =< 0.1, we return a count of 1 piece.  Otherwise, break the piece into 2, 3, or 4 pieces (quantity chosen randomly) and recur.   Return the total count of pieces when all are no larger than 0.1. So far my code looks like this.

```
import random as rand

def breaker_function(weight_of_piece):
    if weight_of_piece <= 0.1:
        return 1 #returns one piece
    else:
        return breaker_function(weight_of_piece/rand.randint(2,4))
```

However, this code does not work. I ran it through the debugger, and when it reached the recursive step, the program broke it randomly (which were not less than 0.1).  Since the pieces were not less than 0.1, the function stopped. I am not getting an error.

I have also tried double recursion(?) such as:

```
return breaker_function(breaker_function(weight_of_piece/rand.randint(2,4)))
```

I have also tried to store the random pieces in a list, but that just complicated things, and got a similar result.

Test case: a starting piece of size 1.0 i should get approximately 18 pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function never returns anything but `1`.  You need to change the recursion step.  Break into equal pieces, and then add the results of breaking each of those pieces:

```
else:
    quant = rand.randint(2,4)
    count = 0
    for i in range(quant):
        count += breaker_function(weight_of_piece/quant)
    return count
```

Running this 10 times:

```
21
22
22
17
20
25
15
18
20
17
```